# How to edit or cut the Y axis limits?

Tags: matlab, plot

I draw the simulation on matlab. But the results was too far away. So I want to cut or break the Y axis by getting rid of the interval [20, 50] and replace it as in the attached picture?. Any suggestions to do that.[image]

Comment: See this blog: https://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/11/21/breaking-a-plot-to-improve-visualization/#3

Comment: Can it works with boxplot. I see the command `BreakPlot(sampleTimes,RPM,1500,5000,'Line');`